# Torsion in Whitehead group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, algebraic-k-theory

Let $\pi$ be a finite group of odd order. What do we know about the torsion subgroup of $Wh(\pi)$? I am especially interested in the $2$-primary part. Is it always trivial?

Comment: I would start with Bob Oliver's Whitehead groups of finite groups. LMS Lecture Note Series, 132. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1988.  It's complicated and technical, but there are a bunch of examples computed in the last section that might answer your question.